# How can I solve fatal exception in android in eclipse in mac?

Tags: android

When I run my Hello World app in Emulator I am facing Fatal Exception,May u know the reason for that..

```
package hsz.developer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="hsz.developer"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

logcat:

```
 07-18 23:16:39.578: E/Trace(754): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable.AppCompatTheme
 07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:336)
07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
 07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:273)
07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
 07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):     at hsz.developer.Main.onCreate(Main.java:13)
07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
 07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
 07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
```

07-18 23:16:40.589: E/AndroidRuntime(754):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: This question needs more information it is impossible to answer as it is now.

Comment: please provide your code and the logcat exception

Comment: Add code and logcat or this quesiton will be shut down

Comment: @Polarbear0106 help me please.

Comment: Calm down! Use Android Studio if you are to use newer versions of android and finally - Learn to solve your own exceptions!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) instead. It's the preferred IDE and it works on Mac.

Comment: Any way to use eclipse?

Comment: Technically you can, but Google reccommends AS. All their modern training materials point to Android Studio. See this thread here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040030/can-i-still-use-eclipse-for-android-projects